# MySQL query returning false

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using XAMPP server. Using phpMyAdmin, I created a database and a table named "Users". When I run the code below, it says `Error in your query`. Whats wrong with my code?

```php
function selectMultiRows($query) 
{    
    if((@$result = mysql_query ($query))==FALSE) 
    { 
        echo "<strong>Error in your query:</strong> <br>$query"; 
    }    
    else 
    {     
        $count = 0; 
        $data = array(); 
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $data[$count] = $row; 
            $count++; 
        } 
            return $data; 
    } 
} 


$query = "select * from Users"; 
$returnedData = selectMultiRows($query); 
$totalRecords =  count($returnedData); 

for($i=0;$i<$totalRecords;$i++) 
{ 
    echo $returnedData[$i]["username"] . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: don't output a fixed/useless error message. have mysql TELL you what the problem is: `echo "query fail:" . mysql_error();`.

Comment: You should first check the mysql_error(), so use $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error()); instead of previous. Then you will get the exact error and can debug.

Comment: It says no database detected but I have created that database in phpmyAdmin  Edit: Also my connection was successful

Comment: have you used mysql_select_db('db_name') function to select database?